# Theorem 8.1 in textbook Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology (Bott and Tu)

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

In theorem 8.1 the following statement is shown:
\begin{equation}
H_D(C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*))\simeq H^*_\text{DR}(M),
\end{equation}
where the lefthand side is cohomology of a double complex and the righthand side  is the de Rham cohomology.

In this proof the map
\begin{equation}
r: \Omega^*(M) \rightarrow \Omega^*(U)\oplus\Omega^*(V)\subset C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*),
\end{equation}
is considered and the commutativity of the following is used.

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\Omega^*(M)& \overset{r}\longrightarrow& C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)\\
d\Big\uparrow& & \Big\uparrow D\\
\Omega^*(M)& \underset{r}\rightarrow& C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The book says it is commutative because
\begin{align*}
Dr &= (\delta + (-1)^pd)r & [\because\text{it is the definition of $D$ and $p=0$}]\\
&= dr = rd.
\end{align*}

I don't understand why operator $\delta$ vanishes in the second line?

p.s.
The double complex $C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)$ is defined,
for open cover $\mathfrak U = \{U,V\}$, as
\begin{equation}
C^0(\mathfrak U,\Omega^q) = \Omega^q(U)\oplus\Omega^q(V),\;\;
C^1(\mathfrak U,\Omega^q) = \Omega^q(U\cap V).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the open cover has only two elements, we know that $\delta$ vanishes when $p>0$. But, regardless, $\delta\circ r = 0$ by definition, since $(r\omega)|_{U\cap V} = (r\omega)|_{U\cap V}$ for any $\omega\in\Omega^*(M)$.

**EDIT**: I had to go look at the book. I see that they haven't been explicit yet about defining the coboundary map on Čech cochains. They do in the paragraphs preceding this theorem say that $\delta$ is the difference map going horizontally. That is, if $\sigma = (\sigma_i)\in C^0(\mathfrak U,\Omega^q)$ is a $0$-cochain (i.e., an assignment of a smooth $q$-form to each open set $U_i$), then $\delta(\sigma)\in C^1(\mathfrak U,\Omega^q)$ is the $1$-cochain that assigns to the open set $U_i\cap U_j$ the $q$-form $\sigma_i\big|_{U_i\cap U_j} - \sigma_j\big|_{U_i\cap U_j}$. Thus, $\sigma$ is a $0$-cocycle if and only if $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ agree on the overlap $U_i\cap U_j$. This means that a $0$-cocycle gives a *global* form on $M$, and conversely.

Comment: Since the double complex $K^{p,q}$ is defined as
$K^{p,0} = \Omega(M)$, $K^{p,1} = \Omega(U\cup V)$ and $K^{p,q} = 0 (p\geq2)$.
I think $\delta$ vanishes when $p\geq1$ but now do we not consider $p=0$ case?

Comment: I gave the argument. The $0$-cochain is in the image of $r$. What does that mean about its coboundary?

Comment: What does $(r\omega)|_{U\cap V} = (r\omega)|_{U\cap V}$
mean...? It looks trivial equation.

Comment: Yes, it is. Write down the coboundary of the $0$-cochain $r\omega$.

Comment: Later in this book 
$\delta: \prod\Omega^*(U_{\alpha\beta})\rightarrow
\prod_\alpha\Omega^*(U_{\alpha\beta\gamma})$,
$(\delta\xi)_{\alpha\beta\gamma}
:= \xi_{\beta\gamma} - \xi_{\alpha\gamma} + \xi_{\alpha\beta}$
is defined. 
Do we have to use this here?

Comment: No. What is the coboundary of a Cech $0$-cochain?

Comment: A coboundary $\omega$ is an element, $\exists\xi$ s.t. $\omega = \delta\xi$.
Am I right..?

Comment: I've edited. The book should have said a bit more for readers not familiar with Čech cohomology.

Comment: thank you so much! (^_-)

Comment: I understood the $p=0$ case. I Later in this book we consider more open covers $U_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ and so on. For a map $C^1(\mathfrak U,R)\rightarrow C^2(\mathfrak U,R)$ $\delta\neq0$?

Comment: That's right. So you're computing the Čech cohomology relative to that open covering and, once you get a "fine" enough open cover, this computes the actual sheaf cohomology of the manifold.

Comment: What is the motivation for defining $\delta$ after $p=0$? For $p=0$ $\delta=0$ implies $\omega$ is a global form and similar meanings for $p\geq1$?

Comment: Keep going in the book.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to actually go into later discussions of Cech cohomology to get this result. The simpler answer is that the vanishing of $\delta r$ follows immediately from the exactness of the sequence:

$$ 0\rightarrow \Omega^*(U\cup V) \overset{r}\longrightarrow \Omega^*(U)\oplus \Omega^*(V) \overset{\delta}\longrightarrow \Omega^*(U\cap V) \rightarrow 0$$

If I recall correctly, the authors discuss this sequence a page or two before Theorem 8.1, and they prove the exactness of the above sequence (in a manner similar to Ted's answer) in Chapter 5.